# java constructor with argument having a max value

Tags: java, constructor

Beginning in Java, i would like that one of argument in constructor not being over a certain value when created.
for exemple :

```
public class Vehicule {
    protected String immat;
    protected int poidsVide;
    protected int charge;
    protected int chargeMax;

    Vehicule(String immat, int poidsVide, int charge) {
        this.immat = immat;
        this.poidsVide = poidsVide;
        this.charge = charge;
        this.chargeMax = 10000;
   }
}
```

i don't want any object instanciated with 'charge' being superior to 'chargeMAx'
how should i do that?
tried several option nothing working so far.

thanks for your help.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried so far? And what do you expect to happen when "charge" is too large? How should your program respond?

Comment: well i would like being impossible to instanciate when trying with a too large number, Vehicule V1 =new Vehicule("777 BA 78",2000, _15000_); schould not compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it seems that your chargeMax is a constant value and it does not need to receive its value (10000) within the constructor. You can do this directly in its field declaration.

Second, you are allowed to put some logic inside your constructor. That logic depends on what you need. You can automatically make charge receive the chargeMax when the constructor receives a value bigger than it.

E.G.:

```
public class Vehicle {
    protected String immat;
    protected int poidsVide;
    protected int charge;
    protected static final int CHARGE_MAX = 10000; // this is a constant

    Vehicle(String immat, int poidsVide, int charge) {
        this.immat = immat;
        this.poidsVide = poidsVide;

        if (charge > CHARGE_MAX){
          this.charge = CHARGE_MAX;
        }
        else {
          this.charge = charge;
        }
    }

}
```

Another idea is to throw an exception when Vehicle receives some unwanted value:

```
Vehicle(String immat, int poidsVide, int charge) {
    this.immat = immat;
    this.poidsVide = poidsVide;

    if (charge > CHARGE_MAX){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Charge cannot be bigger than " + CHARGE_MAX);
    }
    else {
      this.charge = charge;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i didn't know it was possible to add if,else etc... in the constructor.
Yes chargeMax is a constant , thanks really helpfull.